# Tornado Error Handling

Tags: tornado

I want to be able to handle a nicer error that's displayed if i type an incorrect URL `E.g. localhost:8000/AFDADSFDKFADS`

I get an ugly python traceback message because a  tornado.web.HTTPError exception is thrown. I know I can use a regex to catch all scenarios other than my proper URLs however I figure there must be a way to handle this error within Tornado.

I know that I can use the `write_error()` when extending the `tornado.web.RequestHandler` but because this error is happening in the `tornado.web.Application` class I don't know how to deal with it. 
I think it might have something to do with the class `tornado.web.ErrorHandler(application, request, **kwargs)` however I'm unsure.

Also can someone tell me if i'm in a `tornado.web.RequestHandler` method and perform a `raise KeyError` or other exception without catching it why the `write_error()` isn't invoked? It seems the exception is ignored.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with default_handler_class i'm investigating this and will report back

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To provide a custom 404 page make a handler that calls `self.set_status(404)` (in addition to producing whatever output you want) and set it as `default_handler_class` in the `Application` constructor keyword arguments.

```
class My404Handler(RequestHandler):
    # Override prepare() instead of get() to cover all possible HTTP methods.
    def prepare(self):
        self.set_status(404)
        self.render("404.html")

app = Application(..., default_handler_class=My404Handler)
```

You probably don't want to use `ErrorHandler`: it's an easy way to return a specified status code but it doesn't give you control of the output.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the response. My solution was to override the write_error() as follows: `class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
          self.render("error.html",status_code=status_code)` I did read about what you describe in the documentation under Error Handling. Is the default_handler_class only used for 404 errors then? Because from your code it seems to assume it will always be a 404... (i think). I wanted to reuse the class i wrote for all errors not just the 404s? Or would you recommend i create separate classes.

Comment: `default_handler_class` is just for 404s; for other errors you need to define `write_error` in a base class (and then your `default_handler_class` can simply subclass that and `raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)` in `prepare()`.