# Python Catch all errors in Tornado Web Server

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm running Tornado as async application server (not WSGI). I need to catch all server errors for all defined api endpoints / Tornado handlers (like `500 Internal Server Error), so I added this`ErrorHandler` class (according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392952/gracefully-handling-application-exceptions-in-a-tornado-application))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

import handlers as th
from tornado import web

class ErrorHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    """Generates an error response with status_code for all requests."""

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        print('In get_error_html. status_code: ', status_code)
        if status_code in [403, 404, 500, 503]:
            self.write('Error %s' % status_code)
        else:
            self.write('BOOM!')

    def prepare(self):
        print('In prepare...')
        raise Exception('Error!')

def application():

    handlers = [

        # Catch all Error handler
        (r"/", ErrorHandler),

        (r'/data', th.customHandler)
    ]

    settings = dict()
    return web.Application(handlers, **settings)
```

But it does not work. When calling the `/data` endpoint with the `customHandler` causing a 500 error I'm still getting a

```
<html>
<title>500: Internal Server Error</title>

<body>500: Internal Server Error</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It won't work because both are separate handlers. If you call `customHandler`, then the `write_error` method of `ErrorHandler` will not run.

Comment: @xyres yes, so how pass a default error handler in the standard way to Tornado?

Comment: For handling 404 errors, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30966771/1925257. For handling other errors, you'll have to create the `write_error` method in the `customHandler` class. Or you can create a base class and then use it to subclass your handlers.

Comment: this may address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108963/13837927